# Install4j HTML error messages

Tags: install4j

I'd like to display error messages to our users based on validations, and provide them with links on how to solve their issues.

The problem is that using an action's "Error Message" property or Util.showErrorMessage displays plain text messages which the user cannot click. They can't even select the text to copy/past a plain link.

Is there any workaround for this issue? I don't think a full page for this validation errors is worth it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

install4j does not offer such an error dialog, but the installer is a Swing application. You can add a JAR file with your own implementation to the "Installer->Custom code & resources" step and use your class in all scripts.